# Fetching and displaying spatial data from a database into R

Tags: postgis, r

I'm creating a ShinyApp in which I'm trying to display on a leaflet map some spatial data (about 100 MB) fetched from a database.

According to the documentation I've found [here](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pg.html) the code  sample below is the best (only ?) way to import spatial data from a database into R :

```
library(rgdal)
dsn="PG:dbname='my_database' host='localhost' port='5432' user='admin' password='admin'"
ogrListLayers(dsn)
data=readOGR(dsn,"dataset_test")
```

It works well but it takes forever (about 4 minutes) to fully load the file in the R environment.

Thus I tried to fetch my data by mean of a query in postgre:

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(pool)
    
pool <- dbPool(
drv = dbDriver("PostgreSQL", max.con = 100),
dbname = "my_database",
host = "host",
user = "admin",
password = "admin",
port = "5432",
idleTimeout = 3600000
)
    
data <- st_read(pool, query = "SELECT * FROM dataset_test")
data <- st_transform(data, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

leaflet(st_zm(data)) %>% addTiles() %>% addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldImagery, group = "Esri World Imagery") %>% 
addPolygons(fillColor = "#7FFFD4", weight = 3, fillOpacity = 0.5)
```

This method is way faster than the first one but the drawback is that it obviously generates a non-spatial dataframe.

It's the first time I'm fetching data in R from a database and I'm a bit confused about the best way to it...

Could someone help me out please ? :)

**EDIT**:

My two mains questions are :

- Why does it take so long to load a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame of 80 MB from a database to R ? (the same process is done in 5 seconds in QGIS)
- If I have to give up on the idea to display my data in Shiny as a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, what would be the best way to save a dataframe with a geom column (containing coordinates like this: `list(list(c(771256.092575953, 771289.308419454, 771291.892710547, 771256.465456019, 771256.092575953, 6577795.59430757, 6577796.39474202, 6577790.68324772, 6577791.36728974, 6577795.59430757, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))))` to a shapefile ? Thus I could incorporate a download button to my shinyApp for the user to get those data as a shapefile.

Comment: Where's the shapefile here?

Comment: Hey Spacedman ! data=readOGR(dsn,"dataset_test") is actually data=readOGR(dsn,"my_schema.my_shapefile"). Please let me know if I'm totally missing something here before closing my question ! :(

Comment: That's not a shapefile. You are reading from a database, no shapefiles are involved. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile

Comment: Indeed ! I may not have been very clear in my question, sorry ! I just would like to know what was the cleanest and fastest way to display spatial data from my database to Shiny ! Am I going completely wrong in my script ?

Comment: Can you edit your Q and take out mentions of "shapefile"? Because that is incorrect and doesn't help people find your question.

Comment: How dynamic is your data? Is it updated often so that when a user runs the app they need the absolute latest data? Because otherwise you could generate a native R .rds file every so often and use `loadRDS`. Also have you tried using `sf` spatial objects instead of `sp`?

Comment: Is your data complex polygons and lines? Or points? Because reading the table as non-spatial is bound to be much faster when there's no geometries to construct. Do you need to do one query of the whole table or could you rewrite your code to only query selected parts when needed using an additional SQL clause when you read it (with `st_read` if using `sf`, which is recommended...)

Comment: It depends but usually I'm adding new features in the database every 2 weeks. That's why I wanted to fetch the data automatically...
I have another table containing points so I'm already loading them as non-spatial but the one I'm struggling with is made of polygons. I enabled the user to query some part of the table but I want him to be able to query the whole table if he needs to :/

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications or any additional information which you think may be relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a recent version of Postgis then you can output the whole query as geojson and maybe read that using `st_read`? Here is a query you can try: `SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(sub.*) AS geojson FROM dataset_test AS sub`. Paul Ramsey's excellent blog explains this: http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2019/08/postgis-3-geojson.html

Answer (score -1):

I would try using [SF with RPostgreSQL](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/04/interact-with-postgis-from-r/) or rpostgis. My understanding of Rgdal, as described [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/rgdal/man/readOGR.html) is that is uses SP, which as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49258562/comparing-simple-features-sf-and-spatial-objects-sp-speed-and-memory), is usually, but not always, slower than SF.  Using [ST_Simplify](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Simplify.html) may also speed up your query.

In answer to your second question, you could query the geom column with [st_astext](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsText.html).